# Get total CPU usage of an app from simpleperf recording

Tags: android, perf

I'm using simpleperf to profile my Android application, as I found the Android Profiler to be very limited.

I'm recording a sample using

```
./app_profiler.py -p com.foo.myapp -r "-e task-clock:u -f 1000 -g"
```

This then allows me to nicely display the CPU usage of all my threads *relative to the whole app*. Is there a way to show me how much of the available CPU power was actually used? I.e. report *absolute* usage numbers?

Some options I found to be less than ideal:

- `top` shows it live, but doesn't give a good average (same as the Android Profiler)
- `simpleperf stat` to shows it very nicely, but runs independently of the `simpleperf record`
- Add `--duration 60` to the record command and then divide the reported milliseconds for `task-clock` by that amount. This however seems to be off by up to +/-50%! And I have to know in advance how long to record.

The normal `perf` tool has a `perf stat record` command that displays stats based on a recording, which seems exactly like what I'm looking for, but simpleperf doesn't support that.

Comment: `perf stat`'s task-clock *is* absolute CPU-seconds used.  Unless `app-profiler` mangles the output?  Measuring how much of the available CPU power would be a *relative* measure, like `task-clock / (wall-clock * number of cores)`

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's `perf record` (well, `simpleperf record`) that isn't using absolute CPU-seconds. It shows me a percentage (where 100% is the whole app, not the whole cpu). And while it does show me total CPU-seconds as well, I haven't found any `wall-clock` measurement (i.e. how long the recording exactly was) to make use of that number.

Comment: do I just have to record `wall-clock` as well?

Comment: Not sure, sorry.  I just use `perf stat` when I want totals, on my x86 desktop.  I don't do Android.